# Y2 axis showing in decimal in C3 combination chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, c3.js

I have tried C3 Combination chart with the below data. it showing Y2 axis in decimal points. So I couldn't see data2 points in my chart.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
         columns: [
              ['data1', 30543, 2045346, 50765767, 4067657, 605676, 50665],
              ['data2', 200, 130, 90, 240, 130, 220]
         ],
         type: 'bar',
         types: {
              data2: 'line'
         }
     },
     axis: {
         y2: {
              show: true
             }
     }
});
```

Let me know the solution

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your second y-axis wrong. This way you see only one y-axis in with a display range waaay above your second column, that's why it is showed as points.

Just add `axes: {data1:'y',data2:'y2'}`

The complete config of your chart should look like this:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30543, 2045346, 50765767, 4067657, 605676, 50665],
            ['data2', 200, 130, 90, 240, 130, 220]
        ],
       types: {
            data1: 'bar',
            data2: 'line'      
        },
        axes: {
            data1: 'y',
            data2: 'y2'
        }

    },
    axis: {
        y2: {
            show: true
        }
    }
});
```